# In a Stored Proc, looking for table names (maybe with regex?) excluding two schemas

Tags: sql-server, regex, ssms, regex-negation

My company is moving all report generation tables to another server, and to do that we need to find all instances where stored procedures access live tables and remove those accesses and replace them with accesses to snapshots. There are quite a few stored procedures I have to look through, and my eyes are starting to bleed trying to scroll through each file. I thought perhaps a regex would be best to look in each stored proc. Is there maybe an even better way?

I am looking to find all situations where there is a FROM or JOIN followed by a table that does not start with "Snapshot", or "EDI" (two schemas associated with reports). Also, I am sure someone has typed "FROm" on accident, so case-insensitive would be helpful. I am also trying to do \s+ because someone may have typed more than one space in-between on accident.

For example, looking to exclude:

- FROM Snapshot
- FROM EDI
- JOIN Snapshot
- JOIN EDI

and the case-insensitive variants

I have done the tutorial [here](http://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs), but am still coming up short. So far I have:

[fFjJ][RroO][oOiI][mMnN]\s+^(!snap|Snap|SNAP|EDI|edi|Edi)$

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I am using the regex in SSMS 2016 using the Find and Replace functionality.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many stored procs are we talking?  I would think it would be easier to just do a like on the table name (and ignore looking for "from" and "join") and then with the short list, have a human go through and pick out the false positives.

Comment: Probably 100 stored procs. I want to exclude those two schemas because there are hundreds of possible live tables that could be referenced(all on the dbo schema, but the references might not use the dbo qualifier). By excluding those two schema references, I get at the data I want easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have SSMS 2016 in front of me, the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx) seem to suggest that this will work.

```
(FROM|JOIN)\s+~((Snapshot|Edi)\.):a*>
```

Breakdown

```
(FROM|JOIN)          --Match the word from or join
\s+                  --match at least one bit of whitespace
~(                   --don't call it a match if this comes next
   (Snapshot|Edi)\.  --the word Snapshot or Edi followed by a period
)                    --end of the don't match prefix
:a*                  --match any number of alphanumeric characters (this is your table name, so you may need a different character class depending on what characters you use in your tables)
>                    --match the end of a word
```

There should also be an option in the Find and Replace dialog box to do case insensitive matching.

Comment: That is a good point. With "Match case" unchecked, that regex does in fact work for lower case and other combinations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a much better way found [Here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) using T-SQL. I still have to go SP by SP, but it is much faster and less error prone than using a regex and forgetting some boundaries.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name, 
  o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption, 
  COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id, 
  referencing_class_desc,
  referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,
  referenced_entity_name, 
  COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,
  is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'EDI.Populate_IHP_OHN_Eligibility_Report')
  AND referenced_schema_name NOT IN ('EDI', 'Snapshot');
```